# Struggling with understanding the reason why Python needs Virtual Environments

Tags: python

Coming from JavaScript I'm familiar with NPM.

There you can install packages globally (by using the -g flag) or locally in a project. 
In Python they have these Virtual Environments.
I'm still a bit uncertain why they are needed. I know that it is for having the same package in different versions on one machine.

Is it because Python doesn't have the concept of local project-installations?

All package-installations are installed global and there's no way around that. It seems to me being that way ...
**And so they have does Virtual Environments instead?**

I'm a right there?

Comment: I cannot find it stated explicitly in the answers, so I'd like to add that virtual envs do not only provide different sets of dependencies, but each env has its own Python interpreter of desired version (e.g. 2.7 for an old project, 3.6 or 3.7 for other projects).

Comment: In the vm'd/containerized world we live in now, I would argue that you often *don't* really need a virtualenv... or a local node_modules folder. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because Python doesn't have the concept of local project-installations?

Correct.

Well, mostly correct. There's a number of "modern" Python package managers that support project-local package installation. Right now the big two are [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) and [poetry](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry).

However, all of these libraries are fundamentally wrappers over the basic Python virtual environment mechanism. It's the basis of the ecosystem.

Global package management is a little thorny in Python because Unix systems tend to come with a "system Python" installation that support parts of the operating system. Installing/updating packages in the system Python is a **very bad idea**, so you always want to be working in a Python you installed yourself, either a fully separate installation or at least a virtual environment of the system Python.

Answer (score 5):

Virtual environments make possible for you to encapsulate dependencies by project.

Python has no `node_modules` equivalent. When you install something with `pip` it goes to your *site-packages* folder. To find out this folder you can run `python -m site` and it will print out the folders where it will search for packages.

Example on Fedora 29:

```
➜  ~ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/geckos',
    '/usr/lib/python27.zip',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/geckos/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/geckos/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

### pip vs package manager

If you don't use virtual environments you may end up with packages being installed side by side with operating system python packages, and this is where the danger is. Packages may be overwritten and things get messy fast. For example you install Flask with pip then try to install Jinja2 from with package-manager, now you remove Jinja2, and breaks Flask, or you update your system, Jinja2 got updated but not Flask. Or even simpler, you install something with package manager and remove with pip, now the package manager is in a broken state.

Because of this we always use virtual environments, and even separate virtual environments by project.

### Creating and maintaining virtual environments

Nothing prevents you from maintaining you virtual environment in the same folder as your project. This way you will have the same *felling* that you have with node_modules. You can create it with

`virtualenv <SOME_FOLDER>` for python 2
or
`python3 -m venv <SOME_FOLDER>` for python 3

### Conventions that I've seen

If you're keeping virtual environments as a subfolder of your project, I usually call then `env` or `venv`

Other options is keeping all then in the same folder inside your home, I've been using `~/.venv/<PROJECT>`

### Pipenv

Finally there is an alternative that I like more than pure `pip`. Pipenv is a tool that manages virtual environments automatically for you. It feels more close to *yarn* and has more features

To create a virtual environment for a project just `pipenv --tree` or `pipenv --two` in your project folder. It will create and manage the virtual environment and write dependencies to Pipenv file. It also support development packages, I really think is worth trying. Here is the docs: https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/

I hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 1):

There is really no technical reason that requires the use of virtual environments in Python, period.

Nothing in windows, *NIX or any other OS prevents you from having multiple versions of the same library or executable -system or otherwise- installed side by side, and letting every program or project link to their preferred version. Having different versions of the same package installed in one machine is the bread and butter of interoperability and backwards compatibility in every OS.

As for project isolation & encapsulation, folders provide 95% of the required functionality and none of the bloat or disk space waste. Per-project environment variables, if needed, are usually better handled by your favorite IDE.

As for why do they exist at all, they are part of a larger trend towards new developers assuming they have the right to completely take over the user's system by installing all sorts of unnecessary dependencies as well as forcing the user's workflow to conform to their preferred design-philosophy-of-the-day.

Comment: I agree with you, the MS guys have solved the problem of multiple versions years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Package managers basically make it a little easier for library writers or python package maintainers to update versions of the language/libraries without worrying about backward compatibility.

If you come from another language they are a nuisance part of the python ecosystem, but as a practical software engineering matter, if you're going to work with python they are necessary.  You will eventually encounter code where project 1 needs version 1 of library A, and project 2 needs version 2 of the same library.  Without virtual env's, making projects 1 and 2 both work at the same time would require library maintainers to update their libraries as breaking changes were made to upstream dependencies.  That would make life easier for users, but hard for maintainers, and the python ecosystem is optimized for the maintainers.