# why we different environments in Anaconda?

Tags: python

I am not sure why we need to create a different environment in anaconda? To do that, we have to download some python libraries like matplotlib etc. again in that environment which will consume more drive space? My pc is running out of space. Anyone can help me understand it? Also, how to run the python script file directly under the created anaconda environment in the anaconda terminal? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Struggling with understanding the reason why Python needs Virtual Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611159/struggling-with-understanding-the-reason-why-python-needs-virtual-environments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add my opinion after deep diving into python.

I have some programming knowledge for the web (HTML, PHP, WordPress, light javascript), and I've only started working with python about a week ago. It was a mess the first few hours—trying installs, things not compatible with OS version, `$PATH` not always being set correctly, messing with `.bash_profile`, fighting with pyenv and homebrew. It was maddening. Luckily I stumbled onto Anaconda searching for a replacement to pyenv, which removed 99% of my headaches. Now, I honestly wouldn't want to work with python without Anaconda or something like it to manage envs because of how my productivity skyrocketed.

After an hour or so setting up environments, I had it down. I tested some projects from Github and using anaconda made the entire process fast and easy. Within a minute or two I can download a repo, setup the correct python version, install the dependencies and start using the software. Anaconda makes it fast to set things up so you can get to work. I was able to spend my time learning python and dissecting opensource code instead of battling with pyenv and homebrew and my OS.

Besides that, you don't have to worry about system conflicts as everything is being stored away from your global installs and can easily be copied or shared as yaml files. I've been messing with machine learning, image and audio manipulation, etc. and I really wouldn't want all that stuff globally loaded in my system—not to mention, I'd probably run into tons of problems. This way, it's all quarantined. The only system-wide stuff I install are mandatory things only available through homebrew or manually building them.

And if hard drive space is a problem, invest in more hard drives, especially if you want to get into machine learning or work with graphics and audio. Some of the libraries are large, the data piles up, models can be in the GBs each. You'll have lots of data flying around and you'll need the space. I amassed almost 100GB in the past week, but some I can trash. It's worth it though, because I'm learning and working and getting things accomplished.

Lastly, there was some software not even supposed to work on macOS that I was trying to make work. It worked with Anaconda though. Not sure if it was luck or I just did things right, but there you go.

#### So what I've found is so great about Anaconda summed up:

- Speed of setting up and toggling on and off environments
- Separation of installs from the system while still having access to it
- Ability to have many specific python versions installed
- No conflicts or path problems with python version bundled with OS (like mac)
- Simplicity/flexibilty of installing with `conda` or `pip`
- Shorter pip commands (you don't need to use `python -m` or `--user`
- If an env goes awry, you can dump it with one command and start fresh
- The ease of setup allows you to focus on learning and coding instead of troubleshooting

The last point is why I really like it. I'm learning python instead of fighting with installations. It's made the experience way more fun and I've learned way more than I could have without it.

YMMV, but I can't see why anyone wouldn't want to use an env management system.

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda is used to manage different environments which means you can have different versions of python installed on the same computer without having to mix up. For example, if your computer has python 3.8.5 running you can't use a module called `TensorFlow`. So to use `TensorFlow` I installed anaconda to manage different versions of python. It depends on you and the reason why you need different versions of python.

*Anyways to run a python script using anaconda environment, the steps are below.*

1. Open up your terminal window. Create an environment by typing in `conda create -n Stackoverflow python=3.6` You can use any name for your environment instead of `Stackoverflow` Change 3.6 to your desired version of python.
2. After the setup is done. Type in `conda activate TensorFlow` Replace `TensorFlow` to your environment name.
3. Now navigate to your directory where you have your python file. For example if it is in the desktop, type `cd Desktop`
4. To run the python file simply type `python filename.py` in your terminal.

Comment: Thanks Pro Chess. I appreciate your reply that is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, mainly because of version numbers. For example, you might work on a project which uses some code that does not support newer version of some libraries. Then you can account for that.

You can switch the environment in the shell and run the scripts there. More infos about that you can find [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).